# problem with conversion

Tags: c#, linq

This code doesn't return data from table:

```
var pom = from k in dataContext.student_gods
                      where k.skgod == System.Convert.ToString(2002/03)
                      select k.id_stud;
```

This code does return data from table:

```
var pom = from k in dataContext.student_gods
                      where k.skgod== "2002/03" 
                      select k;
```

How to convert a string variable without quotes???

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Of what type is `skgod`?  What do you want to convert the string to, and what do you have against quotes?

Comment: You should probably post or explain the exception you are getting and what you are trying to do when you want help instead of stating it "dont work"

Comment: skgod is string from database

Comment: @skgod:  what is wrong with your second query?  How does it not perform adequately?

Comment: everything is fine with second query but not fine with first query

Comment: @ognjenb: You received a couple of answers. They explain why the first query does not give you the result you're expecting. Does any answer solve your problem? If not, why?

Comment: @ognjenb: so, you're ok then; if everything is fine with your second query, just use it :-)  Seriously though, you need to work harder at asking good questions.  You're getting lots of help in the answers below, but not a lot of feedback from you as to what you're looking for, and how you're not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab at what the OP might be running into, I suspect you have a DateTime object that you'd like to use in a query to compare against a date stored as a string.  If that's the case, you can modify your query to look like:

```
DateTime t = ...
var pom = from k in dataContext.student_gods
         where k.skgod == t.ToString("yyyy/MM")
         select k;
```

Here, you're formatting the date to match what you're expecting to see in your database.  The `ToString` method is formatting the date to return just the year and month components.  Look to the MSDN article on [Custom date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more.

To extend the example, it's currently about 3pm on Sunday, November 22nd.  If I run the following code:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now();
string s = t.ToString("yyyy/MM");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

...I will see **2009/11** printed.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `"2002/03"`, `2002/03` is not a string but the integer division of `2002` by `03` (= `667`).

Are you looking how to convert a `DateTime` to a string?

```
new DateTime(2002, 3, 1).ToString("yyyy/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This returns `"2002/03"`.

Comment: Of course, converting a date time like this would make absolutely no sense whatsoever...

Comment: From the OP's comments to his earlier question, this looks like what he's trying to do. "This means that I will get all students from 2002/03 year"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778586/problem-with-linq-c

Comment: In second query I need something  like this 

> where k.skgod== temp

where is data type of temp char(10) . Temp is column from database table

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is 2002/03 is not what you mean. What are you trying to convert here?
`2002/03` is two integers and a division, and it's value is `2002 / 03 = 667`. If you want the string `"2002/03"` you need to enter that string, `"2002/03"`.

I hope this made sense :)

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert a string variable without quotes???

That doesn't make sense.  String literals *must* be surrounded with quotes, that is what makes it a string.  You cannot just try to convert undeclared variables into strings by their name, it doesn't work that way.  You just need to compare against an actual string, like you do in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

The string `"2002/03"` and `2002/03` are very different things. In C# there are no such things as string literals without quotes. C# is not PHP :-)

`2002/03` is simply an integer division, namely 2002/3 = 667 (note that there are no decimal places, since this is an integer division).

So if you want to compare something with a string, then by all means *use* a string and not an arbitrary calculation result. Keep in mind though, that the `==` operator behaves somewhat erratically when applied to operands of `object` and `string` (since it might be not immediately obvious whether you are doing value or reference equality).